# Download a dmg file by http link

Tags: ruby, http, net-http, dmg

I am trying to download a .dmg file over the http link using ruby script. I have tried NET::HTTP and HTTParty methods described at http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html 
These methods work well with images and other web content but doesnt work for a dmg file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'fileutils'
require 'pathname'
require "open-uri"
require 'net/http'
include FileUtils

#download Software

#Method1
open("VirtualBox-4.2.18-88780-OSX.dmg") do |file|
 file.write('http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.18/VirtualBox-4.2.18-88780-OSX.dmg').read
end

#Method2
Net::HTTP.start("download.virtualbox.org") do |http|
resp = http.get("/virtualbox/4.2.18/VirtualBox-4.2.18-88780-OSX.dmg")
open("VirtualBox-4.2.18-88780-OSX.dmg","wb") do |file|
file.write(resp)
end
end

#Method3
uri = URI('http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.18/VirtualBox-4.2.18-88780-    OSX.dmg')
Net::HTTP.get(uri)

#Method4
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host) do |http|
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
end

#Method5
File.open("~/Desktop/", "wb") do |f| 
f.write HTTParty.get("http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.18/VirtualBox-4.2.18- 88780-OSX.dmg").parsed_response
end

#Method6
File.write('VirtualBox-4.2.18-88780-OSX.dmg',         open('http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.18/VirtualBox-4.2.18-88780-OSX.dmg').read,  {mode: 'wb'})

#Methos7
puts "#{uri}"
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
puts res.body if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
```

How to get dmg file through http link.

Comment: i really don't think that this has something to do with the content that you are loading. are you sure about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume that this is due to a redirect:

```
→ curl -I http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.18/VirtualBox-4.2.18-88780-OSX.dmg
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/virtualbox/4.2.18/VirtualBox-4.2.18-88780-OSX.dmg

→ curl -I http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/virtualbox/4.2.18/VirtualBox-4.2.18-88780-OSX.dmg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 110667450
```

downloading the real url works like this:

```
require 'net/http'
url = "http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/virtualbox/4.2.18/VirtualBox-4.2.18-88780-OSX.dmg"
File.open('tmp.dmg', 'w') { |f| f.write Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body }
```

Comment: Thanks! Where you able to get it working with these changes. It returns with a zero byte tmp file for me.

Comment: sure, it downloaded a 110MB file!

Answer (score 0):

For me this code worked like a charm:

```
Net::HTTP.start("dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net") do |http|
begin
file = open("VirtualBox-4.2.18-88780-OSX.dmg", 'wb')
http.request_get('/' + URI.encode("virtualbox/4.2.18/VirtualBox-4.2.18-88780-OSX.dmg")) do  |response|
  response.read_body do |segment|
    file.write(segment)
  end
end
ensure  
end 
end
```

Answer (score -2):

try shell command like `wget` and execute it with `system` in Ruby

```
system('wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.18/VirtualBox-4.2.18- 88780-OSX.dmg')
```